# Codeigniter displays the auto field of the selected id

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I am using the dropdown to display the fields based on the selected id using ajax onchange.

The fields I want to display are the kode_deskripsi and time_in.

This is my view

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="flex flex-col sm:flex-row items-center mt-3">
                    <label class="sm:w-40 sm:mr-5">Kode Penitipan</label>
                    <select name="kode_penitipan" id="kode_penitipan" class="input w-full border mt-2 flex-1" onchange="getdata(this)">
                        <option>--Pilih Kode Penitipan--</option>
                        <?php foreach ($getKodePenitipan as $key): ?>
                            <option value="<?= $key->kode_penitipan ?>"><?= $key->kode_penitipan ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="flex flex-col sm:flex-row items-center mt-3">
                    <label class="sm:w-40 sm:mr-5">Kode Deskripsi</label>
                    <input type="text" name="kode_deskripsi" id="kode_deskripsi" class="input w-full border mt-2 flex-1" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="flex flex-col sm:flex-row items-center mt-3">
                    <label class="sm:w-40 sm:mr-5">Waktu Masuk</label>
                    <input type="text" name="time_in" id="time_in" class="input w-full border mt-2 flex-1" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and this is the javascript that I made in the view file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getdata(kode_penitipan) {
    var kode_penitipan = $("#kode_penitipan").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url('transaksi/getPenitip') ?>',
        data: "kode_penitipan="+kode_penitipan,
        success: function (data){
            // $('#kode_deskripsi').val(data.kode_deskripsi);
            // $('#time_in').val(data.time_in);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Then this is my controller

```
public function getPenitip()
{
    $kode_penitipan = $this->input->post('kode_penitipan');
    // $query = $this->db->query('penitipan')->where('kode_penitipan', $kode_penitipan);
    $data = $this->M_Transaksi->getAutocomplete($kode_penitipan);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

and this my model

```
public function getAutocomplete($kode_penitipan)
{
    $this->db->where('kode_penitipan', $kode_penitipan);
    $this->db->where('status', '1');
    $query = $this->db->get('penitipan');
    if ($query->num_rows()>0) {
        foreach ($query as $key) {
            $data = array(
                'kode_deskripsi' => $key->kode_deskripsi,
                'time_in' => $key->time_in,
            );
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the field I want to display doesn't appear, I try to use console.log (data) and it turns out to be null. Is there something wrong with my code? Help me ..

Sorry if my English is not perfect, hopefully the points I convey can be understood

Comment: are you able to retrieve the value of  `var kode_penitipan` js variable value correctly??

Comment: I can't get it yet, can you give me the right way?

Comment: now try with this code & let me know what happens??

Comment: Hi, everything seems ok to me in your code . Only thing which is not right here is you have not specify `type` of request in your ajax call so by default request will be `get` but in your backend you are getting your passed parameter using `$this->input->post('kode_penitipan');` i.e : `post` .Either add `type : "POST"` or change your backend code . Also , you need to parse your json so for that use `JSON.parse(data)` and then access same.

Comment: thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your jQuery / Ajax Code is Below:-**

```js
$("#kode_penitipan").change(function(){
  var kode_deskripsi = $(this).val();
  var time_in = $(this).val();
  
  $("#kode_deskripsi").val(kode_deskripsi);
  $("#time_in").val(time_in);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>--Pilih Kode Penitipan--</label>
<select name="kode_penitipan" id="kode_penitipan">
<option value="0">Select Option Value</option>
<option value="Penitipan1">Penitipan1</option>
<option value="Penitipan2">Penitipan1</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" name="kode_deskripsi" id="kode_deskripsi">


<input type="text" name="time_in" id="time_in">
```